# "Whenever possible, prefer" - is it a tautology?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-choice

From the book by Anne Enquist, Laurel Currie Oates, and Jeremy Francis, *Just Writing: Grammar, Punctuation, and Style for the Legal Writer*, § 6.5.2:

> c) Whenever possible, prefer the specific term over the general term.

Isn't it that using *prefer* after *whenever possible* is a tautology, and as such, should be replaced by one of the following versions?

> - Whenever possible, use the specific term over the general term.
> - Prefer to use the specific term over the general term.

Comment: No. Why should it be a tautology?

Comment: I don't think it's tautologous, since it's perfectly okay to say [*you should **usually** prefer](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+should+usually+prefer%22) [some recommended option]*, and that obviously means something slightly different to, for example, ***whenever possible*** or ***always***. But so what if it ***is*** tautologous? There's nothing wrong with tautology.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wonder whether it’s to do with prefer vs use - always preferring something implies usually using that thing, so one might say ‘prefer’ or ‘usually use’, thus avoiding the cognitive gymnastics of deciding whether or not to prefer something that is preferable.

Comment: In the cited (relatively formal imperative) context, ***prefer*** always means ***choose*** (and by implication, ***use***). But consider something like *My style guide says I should always prefer "sick" over "poorly", but personally I prefer "poorly"* I think most native speakers would quite naturally interpret the *second* instance there as having a significantly different meaning - ***I think "poorly" is the better word***, even if I'm dutifully following my style guide and ***actually using "sick".***